# git push to remote, but don't create new branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

Is there a way to `git push`, but, if the branch doesn't exist in the remote, throw an error or exit non-zero instead of creating a new branch on the server?

The use case is the following. I am creating scripts to help automate the scm workflow in my company. If someone accidentally mistypes a branch name as input into the script, I don't want a new branch created on the remote. I already can manually check remote branch existence, but I wondered if git supports this feature.

Comment: Why don't you rename the misspelled branch and delete push again, and then delete the old one?

Comment: I don't want any decisions made by the script. I don't want the script to decide that you meant to have a different branch name or a branch deleted. If the assumptions of the script are invalid, I want it to simply abort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is currently not a way to do this with a single call to `git-push`.**

---

**Possible workarounds:**

Existence of a remote branch can be checked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! git ls-remote --exit-code $remote /refs/heads/$branch
then
    echo >&2 "Error: Remote branch does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Which could be included in a `pre-push` hook as well if desired.  Something like this (place in `.git/hooks/pre-push`):

```
#!/bin/sh
remote="$1"
url="$2"
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
  if ! git ls-remote --exit-code $url $remote_ref
  then
    echo >&2 "Remote branch does not exist, not pushing"
    exit 1
  fi
done
exit 0
```

Which will cause the desired behavior:

```
$ git push origin master:branch_that_does_not_exist
Remote branch does not exist, not pushing
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:some/repository.git'
```

If you have access to the server you can also create a `pre-recieve` hook to reject creation of new branches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings on push.default in git config. Check out the [git config documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to configure it exactly like how you want it (defaults for branching, pushing, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me since I will be providing multiple branch refspecs in the same push and don't need to checkout multiple branches, one after another, to take advantage of push.default